# Error Opening InfoPath forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, 2016

**Client:** Windows 10 with Office 2013/InfoPath 2013, using IE 11 to browse 
 SharePoint 2016

**Issue:**  When you try to open an InfoPath form stored on SharePoint you receive the following message

> "Microsoft Office Error:  This action couldn't be performed because the office doesn't recognize the command it was given."

I believe it has something to do with the Microsoft Office Protocol Handler.  SharePoint is telling it to open it as view only and the handler doesn't seem to like that. If you right-click on the form and click Open in InfoPath it opens right up and works appropriately.

This is only an issue on Windows 10 as we have users on Windows 7 who never have this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the InfoPath form by the two methods below and check the results.

1. Open the InfoPath form by item menu like the picture below.

[image]

2. Modify the view, add the “Name (linked to document)” column into the view and click the column to open the InfoPath form.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will consider these workarounds but I do not consider them solutions.  If anyone has actual solutions I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and it was effecting only the Windows 10 and Infopath 2013 users.

After some examination I found that we had the page set to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

Then I changed this to following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,IE=11,IE=10" />
```

And it is working fine.

Hope this helps.